# Erlang asynchronous httpc post request

Tags: asynchronous, erlang, httpclient

I want to make an asynchronous httpc post request using {receiver, Receiver} and {sync, false}.Receiver can be a pid() but I want to use it as a function with 1 argument which receives an id from which I can extract the pid(). I cannot use pid() here because pid() can change if a process is restarted but id remains same. If anyone can give me an example of how to use receiver as a function. it would be a great help.

Answer (score 0):

In Erlang, you can register process under some name with `register/2`. For example, you can call it, when you start the handler process:

```
register(post_handler, self()).
```

This way, you can use the new name with `!` operator:

```
post_handler ! message.
```

So you can use function as a receiver this way:

```
Receiver = fun(ReplyInfo) -> post_handler ! ReplyInfo end.
request(post, Request, HTTPOptions, [{receiver, Receiver} | OtherOptions], Profile).
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess that when you call httpc:request/4, you know the Id you want to use, and the function to retrieve the corresponding pid, So you just need to create an anonymous function just before calling httpc:request/4:

```
IdRequest = createIdRequest(Request),
ReceiverFunc = fun(ReplyInfo) -> getPid(IdRequest) ! {http,ReplyInfo} end,
httpc:request(Method, Request, HTTPOptions,[{sync, false},{receiver,ReceiverFunc}|Opts]).
```

If you fear that the receiving process died and was restarted (with a new pid) note that doing this (or using registered processes) will still let some time window were the receiving process does not exist (or is not yet registered). The getPid function should deal with this, and anyway the sent message still could be lost (pid dead) or create a crash (process not yet registered).

In my opinion you are looking to recover from error at a too low level, creating useless complexity.